# keyof is not working on 'name' property

Tags: angular, typescript

I've declared an interface Student which has name and lastName property. After that, i created a KEY using **keyof** also declared a variable 'help' of type KEY.

Now I'm initializing variable 'help' with name then it's ok, but when initializing with lastName, I'm getting error **Cannot find name 'lastName'**.

`interface Student {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}`

```
class Greeter {
    constructor() {}

  greeting(): void{
    type KEY = keyof Student;
    let help: KEY;

    help = name;   // ok
    help = lastName;  // Cannot find name 'lastName'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Whats wrong with your code

`name` points to global `name` string : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name. Any `string` can be assigned to the `help` object.

## FIX

Correct Example :

```
interface Student {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}
class Greeter {
  constructor() { }

  greeting(): void {
    type KEY = keyof Student;
    let help: KEY;

    help = 'name';   // ok
    help = 'lastName';  // ok
    help = 'asdf';  // ERROR
  }
}
```